# How to get access token from Okta with spring pre-defined classes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta-api

I have Okta App's client id and secret key and I would like to know how to generate access token using spring default classes and not by hitting the API endpoint.

Please provide the spring pre-defined classes to which I can provide the client id along with secret and the access token is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with server to server authentication. You don't actually explicitly need access token, use oauth2resttemplate for all requests just to have things under control.
You could implement as is from link: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot

Comment: thanks for the link. I will try it out and get back.